# Xamarin/Mvvmcross: Open a different view controller when a iOS push notification is received

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have found this question asked using Objective-c but I am unable to translate it into C#

e.g.
[open-specific-view-when-opening-app-from-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501500/open-specific-view-when-opening-app-from-notification)

Basically I want to do this:

```
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        string alert = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine ("I want to open a specific ViewController and pass in my alert");
    }
```

I am actually using mvvmcross to manage my View navigation. So ideally I want to somehow implement this navigation using mvvmcross. In mvvmcross I would navigate to my ViewControler by doing this:

```
            this.ShowViewModel<SpecificControllerViewModel>();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look to the parameters of ShowViewModel(), it has a way to pass values to the view-model

this is described [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/ViewModel--to-ViewModel-navigation#user-content-navigation-with-parameters---using-a-parameter-object) along with examples

You can achieve that in few ways.
You could use a custom message. A view-model can register to receive the message and you send it from the `ReceivedRemoteNotification` Read [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger) about messenger in MvvmCross.

Or,  you can call ShowViewModel. If you look to how ShowViewModel is implemented [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bbf9a2ac76e74d9404f4b57036c6e29dfe2cc6c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNavigatingObject.cs#L107), it uses a `IMvxViewDispatcher` singleton service, so you could have the following utility method:

```
    static void ShowViewModel<T>(object parameter) where T : IMvxViewModel
    {
        var viewDispatcher = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewDispatcher>();
        var request = MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(typeof(T));
        request.ParameterValues = ((object)parameter).ToSimplePropertyDictionary();
        viewDispatcher.ShowViewModel(request);
    }
```

I posted about this on my blog [here](http://enginecore.blogspot.ro/2014/01/type-safe-viewmodel-to-viewmodel.html).

I think the 2nd way can work even in the case when the notification is received when app is not running (received by `FinishedLaunching`)

Comment: Hi Andrei. Yes I am aware of that. But how to get from the ReceivedRemoteNotification event into my viewmodel is my problem

Comment: did that answer your question?