# APNs: How to perform a segue to go to a specific ViewController when clicking on a Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have completed a news iOS app, and now i would like to implement a push notifications service. I did everything necessary for this to work and it's working just fine. Now i want the app to perform a specific segue depending on data received from the APNs.

**Meaning**: When the user clicks on the notification i want the app to perform a segue to go to some UIViewController.

i couldn't do that using the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method in the AppDelegate.m file.

Do i have to make a class (or a singleton class) in order to perform actions after clicking on a notification ?

**NOTE:** I saw so many questions and answers and i'm kind of lost here, because there are a lot of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Specific View when Opening App from Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501500/open-specific-view-when-opening-app-from-notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u must handle u're notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method . Than u can post `NSUserNotification` and handle it.

u can find answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501892/5100253)

Comment: Ok so far so good, and how can i grab the contents of the APNS data ? and where ?

Comment: @FadiObaji `didReceiveRemoteNotification` has a parameter `userInfo`, not sure whether that's what you mean by "APNS data"