# Open specific viewcontroller when opening app from push notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push

As the title implies: how do I open a specific viewcontroller when a user starts the app by swiping on a push notification?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501500/open-specific-view-when-opening-app-from-notification

Comment: This question shouldn't actually be marked as duplicate because it's tagged swift and the linked question is Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following,

in your apps main view controller "viewDidLoad" method add an observer,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "SomeNotificationAct:",
        name: "SomeNotification",
        object: nil)
```

And also add a method

```
func SomeNotificationAct(notification: NSNotification){     
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("NotificationView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

and add the below code in your "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method of Appdelegate class of your app

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SomeNotification", object:nil, userInfo:someData)
}
```

Comment: what is someData? in 


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]){

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("SomeNotification", object:nil, userInfo:someData)
}