# Navigating to specific view controller when user taps on push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When Push notification arrives, when app is in kill state , I need to navigate to specific view controller from appdelegate when the app is launched by tapping push notification?

//helper method to handle push notification

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString * token = [defaults objectForKey:@"token"];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    if (token!=NULL) {
        // Show the dashboard
        [navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listviewcontroller"] animated:NO];
    } else {
        // Login
        [navigationController pushViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewcontroller"] animated:NO];
    }



}
```

Is this Correct?
or do I need to make any changes?

Comment: I think you need to write code in `ApplicationDidfinishLaunching` to get the notification details when your app is killed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Specific View when Opening App from Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501500/open-specific-view-when-opening-app-from-notification)

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota:i have called this method from application did finish launching

Answer (score 0):

Write your logic in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, where you will get the notification data.

You will get the specific key when user tap on any Notification:

```
launchOptions?["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]
```

If you get this value then you insert the logic of Navigating to specific `UIViewController` else nothing.