# Open specific view controller on click of local notification, if app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to open a specific view controller on click of local notification, if app is in background, i am unable to do that because i don't have `[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];`  in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. Please help if you can, Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15502253/1850983 Check above link. It will help you to solve problem.

Comment: @PayalManiyar Thanks for your answer, I want to do this if app is foreground, the link you mentioned above is fine, if app is not in foreground. How would i know that user clicked on notification, because didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will not called.

Comment: I have given answer. please upvote.

Comment: Thanks please vote up the question too.

Comment: I was not facing the issue so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

do like

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        yourViewController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerStoryboardID"];
       // [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
          self.window.rootViewController = obj;
```

**Update**

```
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
 
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MapViewController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Map"];
// [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = obj;



}
```

**Update1**

you can get the localnotification action in here

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

for complete tutorial see [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/)

Comment: @PayalManiyar - Tanx buddy ,

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik how would i know that user clicked on notification or not?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair - check the updated answer at the same time see this tutorial also it will solve ur issue https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/